# Ubuntu 14.04 getting ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, networking

The problem is out of my league apparently, Ubuntu cannot access any network but somehow my VMs using virtual box are all able to access the internet. I have attempted to do the following changes but as you can this was not successful. I am very confused as to what is wrong on my box. Any help appreciated.

```
carl@carl-Latitude-E6410:~$ sudo ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT
carl@carl-Latitude-E6410:~$ sudo ip6tables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
carl@carl-Latitude-E6410:~$ sudo ip6tables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
carl@carl-Latitude-E6410:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1008ms
carl@carl-Latitude-E6410:~$ sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
carl@carl-Latitude-E6410:~$ sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
carl@carl-Latitude-E6410:~$ sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
carl@carl-Latitude-E6410:~$ sudo service iptables restart
iptables: unrecognized service
carl@carl-Latitude-E6410:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1008ms
```

Comment: Do `iptables --flush` and try again.

Comment: Flushing the iptables did work. I have conflicting ip rules that came with the cisco VPN client... anyways after flushing and reinstalling the client all is good and back to normal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IPtables sometimes gets a little...wonky and there's many rules that don't get removed or get left befind.

Try `iptables --flush` to **delete all your iptables rules**.

Comment: `iptables --flush` deletes all your firewall rules. So yes, it will remove firewall related problems, but is that really what you wanted to do?